# Find the duplicate dates in the same column and increase the date value automatically

Tags: validation, google-sheets, duplicates, increment

I am working on a production planning sheet and there are many projects falling under the same date which are to be forwarded/increased accordingly. Below is the production sheet link

[Planning sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WCaATce1PcWqAS-XwCncr8YM0CE0IKdDQ6rnkJy_a-8/edit?usp=sharing)

Under the H2 ("BOM\RM date w/o increment") & I2 ("Cutlist date w/o increment") cell there are few duplicate dates by which I mean we won't be able to work on 2 or more projects/clients on the same day so except a single client/project we have to postpone the other projects to next day (if there is a Sunday, the project shifts to Monday).
So I am unable to shift the dates with my knowledge of Excel.

So Kindly help me out.

I tried applying "countif" along with "IF" but did not get desired output. Because there are being duplicate value generated again.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand exactly the outcome that you want. Of 40 sample dates, 21 BOM dates and 19 Cutlist dates are unique. But there is no explanation of how these dates are determined, what dates are in-the-past, what dates should be prioritised, the what outcome you are trying to achieve and relevant of weekends in your spreadsheet. Also there is no example of a successful outcome. Would you please edit the question to provide more information about your scenario, BOM and Cutlist dates, how the dates should be adjusted, and include an example of a successful outcome.